# Scrollview not working when focus in EditText on Android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm confused why it doesn't scroll down when my cursor focus inside the `EditText`, in order to scroll you just need to click to the another to scroll down, it there any way how to handle this?

I've Already used this command inside `Layout` but it doesn't work, need help

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

[image]

**The layout above is the child of this activity so this is the parent it's just like onBoarding Screen using `ViewPager`

[image]

The parent `xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Scanner.ScanCashCard">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPrev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="PREV"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id ="@+id/imageIv"
            android:height ="60dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Updated**  I tried `android:fillViewport="true"` like in the following but it didn't work

[image]

**Updated Code**

*Child xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="I. Demographics"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="660dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_hhid"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:counterEnabled="true"
                    app:counterMaxLength="30"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:helperText="Search Household ID!"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_hh">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtHhId"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="160310001-"
                        android:hint="Household no."
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="30" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnSearchHh"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:text="Search"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />


                </LinearLayout>


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_fullname"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_search"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_person">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtFullname"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Full name:"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_clientstatus"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_fullname"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_client">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerClientStatus"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Client status"
                        android:inputType="none" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_address"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_clientstatus"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_location_on_24">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtAddress"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Address"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/til_sex"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_address"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_supervised_user_circle_24"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu">
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerSex"
                        android:layout_width= "match_parent"
                        android:hint="Sex"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_contact_no"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_sex"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_phone_android_24">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtContactNo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Contact No."
                        android:inputType="number" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_set"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_contact_no"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:helperText="Required"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_assigned">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtSet"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Set"
                        android:inputType="number" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>



                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_assigned"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_contact_no"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtAssigned"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Assigned C/ML"
                        android:inputType="text" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/til_minor_grantee"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
                    app:helperTextTextColor="@color/validation"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/til_assigned"
                    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_escalator_warning_24"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu">
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerMinorGrantee"
                        android:layout_width= "match_parent"
                        android:hint="Minor Grantee"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

             </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can anyone know how to handle this error?? I'm using `viewPager` on this area it's like onBoarding screen

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of the ScrollView like this.
And Also add app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf and app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
```

If first doesn't work, try second one.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:fillViewport="true">
```

May be this will fix your issue.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work , also I use `viewPager` on this it's like onboarding screen

Comment: Show your code snippet , I need clear explanation

Comment: Sorry late response, I have added the parent of the activity above, can you check please, still cannot solve the problem

Comment: In your xml ,Scroll view add android:height="wrap content" and android:fillViewport=true 
And also in view pager  add android:height="wrap content".

Comment: I tried but it didn't work I've added `gif` above of what's actually happening and also the updates can you check please, I'm actually stuck with this problem :(

Comment: Someone know how to solve my problem?

Comment: can you still help me please

Comment: Try giving height for the scroll view , something  like 150dp like that if that works.prblm is in your height
else show me your code.

Comment: I tried changing the `layout_height` on my `Scrollview` but the result was always the same , I've posted the code above please check need help

Comment: Put your TextView inside a seperate linear layout. it will work definitely.

Comment: Still not working don't know how to fix the issue I tried putting `LinearLayout` in `textview` like on the image [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTYqq.png)

Comment: I think the problem is on the parent` xml` not on the child xml or in `scrollView` , I tried unmerge them both and only child xml I scroll and it works fine, but when I combine parent and child xml it does not work and this is what I needed